# AWS cognito: Invalid login token error with cognito-identity pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to understand the authentication flow for aws cognito-userpools and cognito-identitypools. I am hitting an error when trying to invoke aws cognito-identity get-id command as below:

I was able to successfully authenticate with the cognito-idp

```
> aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --client-id 8ik2s2uk8d9ekh7k3s1hstlgt --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=testuser@xxx.com,PASSWORD=Pxxx1 --profile dev1

{
    "ChallengeParameters": {},
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "AccessToken": "eyJraWQi..OiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJvcmln...MOssACEgAsP-..A",
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,
        "TokenType": "Bearer",
        "RefreshToken": "eyJj...IuxVj4Vv3EykM1ItEZkpSA",
        "IdToken": "e..QCw"
    }
}
```

After that trying to generate a Cognito ID, see an error.

```
aws cognito-identity get-id --identity-pool-id us-west-2:7exxx27-fxx4-4xxb-bc7c-1107c054e6de --login IdToken=eyJ.....Q3g4TDQ9IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMy

An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the GetId operation: Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName
```

My end goal is to get the temporary credentials invoking the aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity. However hitting another error with that.

```
> aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity --identity-id "us-west-2:7ee6b627-f894-4b3b-bc7c-1107c054e6de" --profile dev1 --region us-west-2.
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetCredentialsForIdentity operation: Identity 'us-west-2:7ee6b627-f894-4b3b-bc7c-1107c054e6de' not found.
```

Not sure how to progress here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized what I was doing wrong. Am able to get the complete auth flow working.

1. Initiate Authentication (cognito-idp)

   ```
    ~> aws cognito-idp initiate-auth \                                                   
   --client-id 8ik2sxxxxh7k3s1hstlgt \                                              
   --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH \                                                     
   --auth-parameters USERNAME=bxxxur@wxxxxxx.com,PASSWORD=Pxxx1 --profile dev1
   {                                                                                    
    "ChallengeParameters": {},                                                       
    "AuthenticationResult": {                                                        
        "AccessToken": "whYhsUITzQQ3eBXAwI6VX7Gi7Dmv2eP3T1w",                        
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,                                                           
        "TokenType": "Bearer",                                                       
        "RefreshToken": "RwrB-FIu6ZaQkv3AP_htR9QhD.hHZoXervix8HcvMnyi8oVw",          
        "IdToken": "Ngf2ZbCZZ-FJwY-7ptPGpKMdA7NjjYVX8hM7DA"                          
    }                                                                                
   }
   ```
2. Get cognito pool ID

   ```
   %~> aws cognito-identity get-id \                                                   
   --identity-pool-id us-west-2:7ee6b627-f894-4b3b-bc7c-1107c054e6de \                  
   --login  cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west- 
   2_BLcbQ9DHK=eyJraWQiOiJlMF.....Z20mCsfhv4RHy0GSdJxLvZkZ-
   w10Gloz8cApb71QrvxY2vPvqq0klDvWzeA
   {                                                                                    
      "IdentityId": "us-west-2:bbc7f768-1a17-4c02-8f48-56d2e84c3947"                   
   }
   ```
3. Get credentials for identity

   ```
   ~> aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity \                               
   --identity-id us-west-2:bbc7f768-1a17-4c02-8f48-56d2e84c3947 \                       
   --login  cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west- 
   2_BLcbQ9DHK=eyJraWQ......sj5bOd3hu824g --profile dev1
   {                                                                                    
    "IdentityId": "us-west-2:bbc7f768-1a17-4c02-8f48-56d2e84c3947",                  
    "Credentials": {                                                                 
        "AccessKeyId": "AS....O57QPE",                                               
        "SecretKey": "f....CJsfDV5Y2jW",                                             
        "SessionToken":"IQWvwc.......BDXm+5khWB5m/NWYUbf7leZ/Sk2f2y4Le",            
        "Expiration": 1641857034.0                                                   
    }                                                                                
   }
   ```